# create a sub website of the parent website for each user(sub domain or subfolder)

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, subdomain

My client asked me to create a new sub folder or sub directory for each user. My main URL is like `www.mysite.com`, after creating a user the user should be able to access it as `www.mysite.com/userName` or `www.userName.mysite.com`. Is it possible to do through JSP, i dont know exact what key words should be used to search in google for this problem. I use JSP, Apache tomcat 5.5, mysql 5.0 for my development. Do i have to copy all the contents to subfolder do this? If so where i could get some help or tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

that can be done in httpd.conf e.g.

```
ServerName www.userName.mysite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.userName\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
```

Comment: could you be more specific? Anyway thanks for your help. let me try with "httpd.conf" in google